# libstdc++.so missing GLIBCXX_3.4.15 and GLIBCXX_3.4.20

Tags: gcc, libstdc++

I've got two Linux installs. The first is an Ubuntu VM on which my project compiles without a hitch. (This VM was set up by someone a former colleague. I'll come back to this later.) The second is a remote CentOS install that I'm setting up to build the same project.

While building the project on the CentOS install I'm encountering the following error at link time

```
../boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::invalid_argument::~invalid_argument()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
../boost/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
../boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
../boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::overflow_error::~overflow_error()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
../boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
../boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
```

When I run the command `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` I find that `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` and `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` are indeed missing. (BTW, what does GLIBCXX mean? is it the ABI?)

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

BTW, I built gcc 4.9.2 on the CentOS machine (to match the Ubuntu machine). Here is the `gcc -v` output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
```

So clearly I need to build gcc differently in order to have `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` and `GLIBCXX_3.4.20`. How do I go about doing this?

---

**Ubuntu VM specs**
(Given for comparison. Note that both are GCC 4.9.2)

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

GCC version

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but Ubuntu's GCC version isn't the same as your GCC build. Note the version, " 4.9.2-10ubuntu13". Ubuntu patches it.

I suggest using a newer compiler, perhaps 5.x or 6.x.